# Inverse sides always returns an empty collection for a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

*This is something I've done before, so I'm quite confused as to why it's not working.*

I have two entities `Question` and `Qresponse`. `Question` is the **owning** side and `Qresponse` is the **inverse** side. When I use doctrine to find all Questions, the **qresponses property** is always empty.

```
//$questions is populated, but the qresponses property is always empty
$questions = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Question::class)->findAll();
```

Why is it empty ? What am I doing wrong?

**Snippet of Owning side: Question**

```
/**
 * Class Question
 * @package Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Question
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->qresponses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @var ArrayCollection $responses
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Qresponse", mappedBy="questions", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $qresponses;
}
```

**Snippet of Inverse side: Qresponse**

```
/**
 * Class Response
 * @package Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Qresponse
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $question
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="qresponses", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="qresponse_question")
     */
    private $questions;

}
```

**Image of database that is populated.**

[image: image of database that is populated]

**Image from the profiler in symfony showing that qresponses is empty...**

[image: image from profiler in symfony showing that qresponses is empty]

Comment: What is the response from `doctrine:schema:validate`?

Comment: @KhorneHoly [OK] The mapping files are correct. and [OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, it's just a typical doctrine hydration issue.

Doctrine by default uses lazy loading, that means associations are only loaded when needed (e.g. when `$question->getQResponses()->first()->getId()` is called). You can easily change it by setting doctrine `fetch` option to EAGER in your association:

```
/** 
 * @var ArrayCollection $responses
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Qresponse", mappedBy="questions", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $qresponses;
```